# Get point with minimum x from 2D numpy array of points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, min, point

This code snippet:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [0, 4], [3, 5]])
print(a[np.argmin(a[:, 0])])
```

prints coordinates of the point with minimum X coordinate from array `a` of points [x, y]:

```
[0 4]
```

Is there a more direct Numpy function than `a[np.argmin(a[:, 0])]` to accomplish the same task?

Comment: `print(min(a, key=lambda x:x[0]))`

Comment: I think the correct answer is "no"; your approach seems good. Using pure python instead of numpy for dubious syntax improvement will be inefficient in practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function (i.e. not `np.min()`), which accepts an optional `key` argument, which is a function implementing how the comparison of elements is to be done. Here this would be

```py
min(a, key=lambda point: point[0])
```

The `point[0]` simply extracts what you refer to as the x coordinate of each point. The returned value is the entire point for which `point[0]` is the minimum value.

Whether the above is "more direct" than `a[np.argmin(a[:, 0])]` is really up to you. They work in essential the same way; looping over `a` while keeping track of the so-far minimal point (as an index for `np.argmin()` and as a reference to the point for `min()`). Though both run in O(n) time, I'm confident that `a[np.argmin(a[:, 0])]` will be the fastest for large arrays.

For a more direct solution *using NumPy*, I don't think one exists. Even if NumPy contained a "`np.minx()`", this would certainly be implemented in a similar fashion and provide no additional benefits.

##### (Overly?) fancy implementation

In the above `min()` solution, we construct an anonymous function on the fly for the extraction of element `0`. The standard library in fact contains a [factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) specifically for creating such functions:

```py
import operator
min(a, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Again this is equivalent, but may or may not look better on the page depending on preference :-)